# Unconfirmed translation

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent 1500 from my wallet address last 2weeks transaction faild to confirm transaction id
1624600252fd611c8d07ae4f6a7922850ea52014d93265fa7340979e8fd55647

Answer (score 0):

For the next time:

Start using a wallet that uses native SegWit addresses `bc1...`. If you had been spending from a `bc1` address and had paid the same feerate your transaction would have confirmed instantly.